# Why do we go beyond two-body interaction?

Tags: forces, condensed-matter, many-body, interactions, quantum-hall-effect

Actually, my question is *why do we study many-body interactions*. I have just started working in Fractional quantum Hall systems. There we have Coulomb interactions between electrons, which we know is a 2-body interaction. But then we go further and study >2 body interactions. If Coulomb interaction is 2-body, what is causing >2 body interactions?

Comment: Well, most systems we know contain more than 2 bodies, don't they? So if we want to understand say orbital mechanics with more than sun + earth (adding jupiter, mars, ...), we need to solve equations which go beyond the 2-body paradigm.

Comment: @DomDoe the question is not on an interaction which is the sum of 2-body interactions but on potential energies which are irreducible functions of N variables.

Comment: It must have to do with not having poles for magnets but always dipoles. the geometry of the dipoles has a collective effect::orientated randomly the magnetic  field cancels,, when ordered it appears. whereas the field from  electric charges will be always there.,thinking of single charges orientation is irrelevant to vector addition of fields.

Comment: @GiorgioP exactly! Can effective many-body interaction arise from some collective behavior even if we just have Coulomb interaction between the particles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In condensed matter, n-body interactions are the rule more than the exception. How do they appear, taking into account that at a fundamental level the relevant interaction is the pair-wise Coulomb interaction?

Simply because in many cases there is need of averaging over some of the the degrees of freedom. As a  prototype example, let's look how one can derive an inter-atomic interaction between atomic degrees of freedom, by "averaging" over the electronic degrees of freedom (basically the Born-Oppenheimer approximation).

No doubt that the complete form of the interaction Hamiltonian can be written as a sum of pair-wise interactions: nucleus-nucleus, nucleus-electron and electron-electron Coulomb interactions. However solving the resulting Schrödinger equation would be a very complex task. In many cases it is possible to justify reduced description where one splits the problem in two steps

1. evaluate the electronic ground state $E_{GS}( \left\{ {\bf R_i} \right\}  )$ at fixed nuclei positions $\left\{ {\bf R_i} \right\}$;
2. treating the nuclei as interacting via an interaction which is 
   $$
   U(\left\{ {\bf R_i} \right\} )= \sum_{i<j} \frac{Z_iZ_j}{\left| {\bf R_i-R_j}  \right|} +E_{GS}( \left\{ {\bf R_i} \right\}  )
   $$
   In general, there is no physically justified way to write $E_{GS}( \left\{ {\bf R_i} \right\}  )$ as a sum of pair-wise terms. On the contrary, there are direct experimental proofs that the total potential energy cannot be put in the form of a sum of pairwise terms.

A simple signature comes from elasticity theory: in a cubic crystal, for symmetry reasons, there should be three independent elastic constants. However, if the interaction potential is pair-wise, there is a relation among the three constants ([Cauchy relation](https://books.google.it/books?id=1q_SBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA230&lpg=PA230&dq=cauchy%20relations%20elastic%20constants%20pairwise&source=bl&ots=sHNvybbYtr&sig=ACfU3U01QUxffM_sZ0jTu0nMHffFePbzUw&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiu2fy6sJ_iAhWSsaQKHQ_ZDKoQ6AEwCHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=cauchy%20relations%20elastic%20constants%20pairwise&f=false)) and one would remain with only two independent elastic constants. Experiments tell us that Cauchy relation is violated in the majority of the experimental systems.

Comment: Although it was a satisfactory answer, as it points to shortcomings of restricting to only 2-body interactions, but is it possible to get some universal intuition of why 2-body picture fails in different areas of physics?

Comment: @AbhishekAnand Very briefly, partial average of a non liner function of a sum of pairwise interaction does not result into a sum of averages. I do not know if this is intuitive, but it is a mathematical fact.